# What signal does upstart/initctl use to restart a job?

Tags: upstart

What signal will `upstart`/`initctl` use to restart a job? Furthermore, is there any way to specify that SIGHUP should be used?

Alternately, is there a way to define a custom `reload` command that will send a SIGHUP? Or do I need to go outside of `upstart` to do that?

Comment: I believe it's SIGQUIT; The response to SIGHUP is application specific in most cases.

Comment: That would make sense. See my clarification edits.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> What signal will upstart/initctl use to restart a job?

`SIGTERM`

```
$ strace -fp `pgrep cron` 2> ~/strace &
$ initctl restart cron
$ cat ~/strace
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, NULL, {0x804a280, [CHLD], SA_RESTART}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
nanosleep({60, 0}, {57, 153662204})     = ? ERESTART_RESTARTBLOCK (To be restarted)
--- SIGTERM (Terminated) @ 0 (0) ---
Process 2275 detached
```

> Furthermore, is there any way to specify that SIGHUP should be used?

Use: `initctl reload`

> Alternately, is there a way to define a custom reload command that will send a SIGHUP?

Use: `initctl reload`

> Or do I need to go outside of upstart to do that?

Use `initctl reload` or `kill`/`killall -HUP`

Comment: Very thorough. Thank you. Guess I could have found some of that on the man page!

Comment: It's upgraded to a SIGKILL if the service doesn't stop in time. "Stopping a job involves sending SIGTERM to it. ... However, if the service takes more than kill timeout seconds (default, 5 seconds) then it will be sent SIGKILL" http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#pre-stop